# how does ThenRun in CompletableFuture work?

Tags: java, completable-future

The main function outputs only 1, 2 and 3. Why does the Runnable in thenRun not run and print 4 as well?

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.lang.Thread;

  class CF {
  static void doSomething() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("ggwp");
    }
  }
 
  static CompletableFuture<Void> printAsync(int i) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      doSomething();
      System.out.print(i);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    });
  }
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAsync(1).join();
    CompletableFuture.allOf(printAsync(2), printAsync(3))
      .thenRun(() -> printAsync(4));
    doSomething();
    }
  }
```

However, when I change the doSomething function as shown below, all the numbers 1,2,3 and 4 will be printed.

```java
  static void doSomething() {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that ever completes any CompletableFuture.

Comment: Not only that. The call `.thenRun(() -> printAsync(4))` creates a `CompletableFuture`, in which ANOTHER `CompletableFture` is created and executed (asynchronously). If we replace this line with `.thenRun(() -> printAsync(4).join()).join();`, then we get the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoke `doSomething()` from `printAsync()` and each invocation puts the invoking thread to sleep for 100ms. Therefore you don't wait long enough to see the output of `4`.

You can use `join` as suggested in the comments to wait until all submitted tasks are finished. Or (to help understand what is happening) you can add a parameter to `doSomething` to specify the amount of ms to sleep and wait a bit longer in your main thread, as shown below.

It is not that the `printAsync(4)` is not executed. Rather, the jvm terminates the process because all non-daemon threads (in this case the main thread) are done before that point.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.lang.Thread;

  class CF {
  static void doSomething(long sleep) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(sleep);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("ggwp");
    }
  }
 
  static CompletableFuture<Void> printAsync(int i) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      doSomething(100);
      System.out.print(i);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAsync(1).join();
    CompletableFuture.allOf(printAsync(2), printAsync(3))
      .thenRun(() -> printAsync(4));
    doSomething(500);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `.thenRun(() -> printAsync(4).join()).join();` will create another `CompletableFuture` and complete it, giving you the expected output.

Comment: Lets say we ignore using .join(), why does the first case not print 4 though? thenRun waits for the allof to run finish then it runs the runnable from what i understand so i thought it would print 4. I'm probably misunderstanding as I just started learning about CompletableFuture.